# Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given

Tags: php

I am using `implode()` like this

```
$var = implode(',', $dataColumns);
```

and get a strange error

> Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stackoverflow! I noticed that your question might need a bit more context to make it clearer. Can you please provide some additional details so that the community can better understand what you're asking? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php Check your parameter order

Comment: This `implode` looks correct ! maybe the issue is in other part of the code

Comment: Did you check whether any other parts of your code throw that error? I can't reproduce it

Comment: @NicoHaase it can be [easily reproduced](https://3v4l.org/FjEe2)

Comment: @YourCommonSense good to know - I haven't thought of using null

Answer (score 9):

This error is not very clear and rather misleading. As far as I know, the message will be fixed in the future, to be made more precise.

Actually it means that you are trying to implode a `null` value. And PHP should raise an error in this case, because only arrays are implodable, while trying to implode a `null` could mean a possible flaw in the program flow.

To fix this error, simply make sure that implode isn't called on a null value (as it makes no sense whatsoever): either fix the input value or don't call implode at all, when there is nothing to implode.

Only as a last resort, if you have no control on the code that provides the array, you can silence this error with a workaround like this

```
implode($separator, $array ?? []);
```

When `$array` is `null`, this code will return just an empty string. But you must understand that it's just as bad as any other error suppression. So again, it's better to fix the error, not the symptom.

---

As to why the error message is so cryptic. It's because [implode has *two* signatures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php): one involving two parameters and one just a single parameter:

```
// just two familiar parameters, a glue and array
implode(string $separator, array $array): string

// Alternative signature, array only without a glue
implode(array $array): string
```

And when implode is called with two parameters, *but the the second one is `null`*, implode *thinks* it is called with just one, where implode expects an array but gets a string, and thus it complains, emitting the error you see.

Comment: Nicely written explanation. A perfect dupe target.