# Laravel Error: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel

**Question:**

I'm facing a new issue with my Laravel script, particularly on the registration page. Initially, I encountered a 505 error, which was resolved with the help of a friend. However, a new error has arisen, and I'm looking for assistance in resolving it.

**Error Message:**

I'm receiving the following error message:

```
TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given 
(View: /home/divetrad/app.divetrade.ng/core/resources/views/user/user/auth/register.blade.php)
```

This error occurs when I access the registration page at https://app.divetrade.ng/register.

**Additional Information**:

I've examined my `.env` file, and here's its content:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:qQ6t+84k29Gnx/6SA1NsdTYsq2GmiSMYHDqwLFERzfs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://app.divetrade.ng

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxxxxxxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=t
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

VTPASSUSERNAME=
VTPASSPASSWORD=
MODE=0
CABLECHARGE=100
POWERCHARGE=100
WAECCHARGE=200
WAECRESULT=100
```

**Screenshot**:

You can view a screenshot of the error message at this link: [Screenshot](https://snipboard.io/lJ8mcD.jpg).

**What I've Tried**:

I've attempted to review my `.env` configuration and ensure that it's correctly set up. However, I may have overlooked something, and I'm seeking guidance on what might be causing this TypeError and how to resolve it.

**Expected Outcome**:

I expect the registration page to load without errors, and I would appreciate any insights or solutions to fix this issue.

Comment: Look at register.blade.php. The screen will actually show you where the error is, if you scroll to line 4, which you have hidden in your screenshot.

Comment: It's unclear why you consider the .env file relevant here? Try to provide a [mre] of the issue instead. See also [ask]

Comment: this: https://snipboard.io/5CoLZP.jpg ?

Comment: On a side note, this is why I resent Blade. Those @php blocks are blasphemous

Comment: Yes that. The duplicate post in the blue box which is now above your question has an excellent explanation of the error, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77072394/5947043 . Basically... probably your $info["code"] variable is null. So now you have to debug that and try to find out why. We can't see where that variable came from or how it was populated (or not populated, as the case may be!)

Comment: P.S. For future reference: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Eh, it can be useful at times. But the way it's being done here doesn't make sense. All that logic can easily be put into the controller.

Comment: ^ Second what aynber is saying re: PHP code blocks. I can count the number of times I've used `@php ... @endphp` in `.blade.php` files on 1 hand in over a decade of working with Laravel. It's a MVC framework (loosely), and there should be no reason the PHP block in that screenshot cannot be done in the Controller and passed forward to the view. There are far more blasphemous things that Laravel does (or allows) than those 